# How to update only specific part of repository?

Tags: apt, updates, repository

### Problem:

I don't use `apt-src` and `apt-file` frequently. But as they are installed, whenever I update repository information with `sudo apt update`, all repositories including repositories of sources, files, gets updated. As my connection is metered, I don't this to happen.

### What I want:

Is there any tweaks or configuration for apt so it will update repository information only for binary deb packages? Or any command like `sudo apt update --deb-packages` or `sudo apt update --sources` ? I want that the way will be easily reversible. No problem if need to write scripts or make my hand dirty by executing commands in terminal.

### What I tried:

I have tried to comment `deb-src` entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` . But this does not turn off files repository and when in need to update sources repository again, I need to uncomment all `deb-src` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to **ignore configuration made by `apt-file`** .

I searched files owned by `apt-file` and found that a configuration file for apt is located at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50apt-file.conf` . I read the contents and there was this text in comment:

```
## This file is provided by apt-file(1) to download Contents
## files, which is used by apt-file for searching.
```

So, I commented whole configuration like this:

```
## This file is provided by apt-file(1) to download Contents
## files, which is used by apt-file for searching.
/*
Acquire::IndexTargets {
    deb::Contents-deb  {
...
# descriptive header.
apt-file::Parser::Check-For-Description-Header "false";
*/
```

Then I ran `apt update` and `apt` is now no longer downloading repository for `apt-file` . Whenever I need to use `apt-file` , I just uncomment those line in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50apt-file.conf` file.